# What is the difference between JWT and signed cookies?

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, express, jwt

I'm looking into [JWT](http://jwt.io) as an alternative to traditional sessions with cookies but I fail to see how they differ fundamentally from signed cookies that for example Express is offering through middleware like [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser).

In both of them, the last part is the signature of the payload which guarantees the payload hasn't been tampered with.

Signed cookie:

```
user=tobi.CP7AWaXDfAKIRfH49dQzKJx7sKzzSoPq7/AcBBRVwlI3
```

Equivalent JWT:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiVG9iaSJ9.kCTlR_Igb4H5cqBEDedShM2ivSQijPQkWqN4pZAXb2g
```

Besides the facts that:

(1) JWT doesn't come with origin restrictions and that

(2) the cookie content is immediately human-readable, whereas the JWT content (header + payload) are base64 encoded

is there anything that gives JWT a clear advantage over signed cookies?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beware of mixing the concerns: cookies are primarily a mechanism for storing data on the client, they aren't inherently an authentication mechanism - but we use them that way :)

The primary benefit of JWTs are the declared structure (JSON, with common fields) and the declared mechanism for signing them.  This is all just specification, there is nothing special about it.  But it is nice to have a common way of persisting identity assertions.

You still need to store your JWT in a secure fashion, and cookies with `HttpOnly; Secure` are the best option.  This prevents the cookie from being read by the JavaScript environment, which prevents XSS attacks.

I've written some blog posts about JWTs, they contain more information that will help to answer your question:

[Build Secure User Interfaces Using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-secure-user-interfaces-using-jwts/)

[Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

Disclaimer: I do work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com).  We sponsor open-source JWT libraries for Node.js and Java, which can be found here:

https://github.com/jwtk

If you are using AngularJS, we also implement JWT best practices out of the box with our [Stormpath Angular SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs)

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are typically used to protect web applications. The browser will add them automatically to every request. This makes the requests vulnerable to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks.

JWT tokens are typically used to protect Web APIs. The token is attached to the AJAX request in JavaScript. Since the token is not attached to the request automatically, the request is not vulnerable to CSRF attacks. JWT tokens can also be used cross-origin in case the API you're talking to is on another domain.

JWT tokens are also used in native clients to talk to web APIs.