# Node JWT library njwt verifies a token even though it differs from original

Tags: token, jwt

Trying out Stormpath's [njwt package](https://github.com/jwtk/njwt) for handling JWTs as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31545145/1787400) by @robertjd.

While trying to see what the various error messages are when `verify()`ing a token, changed a single character (the last one) of a token expecting the verification to fail, but to my surprise it passed and showed the contents of the token correctly.

More precisely, I changed the last character from an `A` to a `B`. This seems to not be the general case, since making other single character changes leads to the expected `JwsParseError` with message `Signature verification failed`. I tried this with both the default `HS256` and with `HS512`.

Is that behavior legitimate for JWTs i.e. that the last char is redundant and doesn't affect the verification checksum? Or is it an issue in the njwt library?

Sub-question to `njwt`'s maintainers: in getting back the token after verification, the header's `algo` property always has a value of `none`. I see in your source code that you explicitly set it so. Why is that?

**Update**: regarding the sub-question for the `"algo": "none"` in njwt's callback of `verify()`, it seems that `"none"` signifies that the digital signature is not included, which is the case when we get the token in the callback. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the base64 (technically, base64url) encoding, which is defined in [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5).  The low-order bits of the final (non-padding) character in the encoded data might not be used, so changing from `A` to `B` might not have a material effect on the decoded value.

Try changing any character but the last :)